# Format date to MM-day-hour

Tags: javascript, date

I have a Date that looks like `2019-07-22T20:58:22`. This is the format I get back from our backend.

How can I convert it to Jul-22 20:58 ? I do not need any other info like years and month has to be in that three letters format.

Comment: put more description like what type of `database` you're using and what you've tried so far

Comment: While you *can* do this by parsing to a Date then formatting, it's much simpler to just reformat the string, replacing the month number with the equivalent short name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const yourDate = '2019-07-22T20:58:22';
const formattedDate = moment(yourDate).format('MMM-DD HH:mm');

console.log(formattedDate); // "Jul-22 20:58"
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: lol!! coz u ask a duplicate question @EissonAlipio

Answer (score -2):

That is an iso 8601 format. You may use the moment library to parse your date to any format you need.

Please note this also looks like a duplicate to the following. see link for an excellent overview of your issue

[duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735724/how-to-parse-iso-8601-into-date-and-time-format-using-moment-js-in-javascript)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, you should vote to close it as a duplicate, not post a comment as an answer with a link to the duplicate.